# How can I separate my TransactionScopes so they don't interfere with each other?

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactionscope

I have some business logic that executes within a simple TransactionScope:

```
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {

            // does some logic.

            // then some more...

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

During execution an ADO exception occurs and the transaction is on it's way to being disposed.

In the meantime the exception is captured further upstream, and I try to log it to my database, via another connection.

At this point I get another error saying `The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.`

Eeek!

Now I can see I am able to use [IsolationLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms679234.aspx), to change the way my transactions interact, but is this the right thing to do? And which should I use?

Comment: Sounds like all of your code is running inside on big DTC-transaction, correct?

Comment: not sure what you mean? as above..during this particular execution the only transaction I am explicitly creating is as above.

Comment: Yes but multiple connections can lead to distributed transactions, you mentioned a second connection against the database

Comment: Did suppressing the transaction while logging resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are mentioning multiple connections and the error you are referring to is something I have seen with DTC transactions I am guessing you are running DTC and that the state of the transaction is faulted due to the AdoException. Try putting a "RequiresNew" transaction scope around your logging code or post more of your code, its hard to see your architecture from that small snippet.

Take a look at this answer showing how two connections can cause DTC to kick in based on which version of sql server you are running:
[TransactionScope automatically escalating to MSDTC on some machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines/1693795#1693795)

Answer (score 1):

As your problem occurs because the transaction is being rolled back / disposed, I'd see two options: using a new transaction or no transaction at all to log. I'd probably go with the second option and log without a transaction.

You can pass a parameter of type [TransactionScopeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the  `TransactionScope` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6ksw5zc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to suppress transactions for your logging statements like this:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)
{
    // .. log here
}
```

To log within a new transaction pass `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`.

Answer (score 0):

you can not have two connections open in transaction scope. close first connection, then open connection for logging error in db.
have look at this ["The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction" error and transaction scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193154/the-operation-is-not-valid-for-the-state-of-the-transaction-error-and-transact)