# Using TransactionScope with two DBContext, get error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope

I have a function which uses `TransactionScope`. When i use two `dbContext`, it crashes. The error message is:

```
System.Data.EntityException: Error underlying provider Open. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. in System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase (InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction AtomicTransaction, Guid promoterType) in System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase (IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Guid promoterType) in System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase (IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification) in System .Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull (Transaction tx) in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist (Transaction tx)
in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection (Transaction transaction) in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection (DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction) in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout , allowCreate Boolean, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions UserOptions, DbConnectionInternal & connection) in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
  UserOptions, DbConnectionInternal & connection) in
  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection (DbConnection
  owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions UserOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal & connection) in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal (DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions UserOptions) in
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner (TaskCompletionSource1 retry) in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen (TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () in System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection. OpenStoreConnectionIf (Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String ExceptionCode, attemptedOperation String, Boolean & closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
```

Code

```
public void example(int c, IEnumerable<int> pi, string comm)
{
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead }))
    {
        var idsList = pi.ToList();
        foreach (var playlist in Context.pl.Where(p => idsList.Contains(p.pid) && p.c== c&& p.stat== 1))
        {
            playlist.TimestampAuthorized = null;

            var pl = "sss";
            notif.generateNotifForUser((new Notification(1, 1, pl, 2, 2)));
        }
        Context.SaveChanges();
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the `Context.SaveChanges()`;
If I comment the line `notif.generateNotifForUser();` it works. Into that function, I also do `context.saveChanges();`

Thanks

Comment: Knowing the details of the exception would be helpful, such as its type, message, etc.

Comment: I added into the post.

Comment: Can you provide the exception message in English please.

Comment: Could be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/193154/1260204

Comment: If `notif.generateNotifForUser((new Notification(1, 1, pl, 2, 2)));` is causing the error then you need to show us what that method looks like

Comment: Already tried another kind of isolation level? And you have MSDTC running right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// code before unchanged
foreach (var playlist in Context.pl.Where(p => idsList.Contains(p.pid) && p.c== c&& p.stat== 1).ToList()) // added ToList
// code after unchanged
```

The issue has to do with the fact that you are trying to use an open connection for 2 things. Iterating the `pl` DbSet results and whatever you are doing in `generateNotifForUser` which is where you are probably getting/doing something else from the DbContext (*based on your update you are making a SaveChanges call*). To fix this add `ToList` at the end of your Lamda statement to force the query results  to be materialized in full immediately  before the iteration starts. Then the connection will no longer be open allowing you to continue to use the `DbContext` in other parts of your code. This also assumes you are not making similar mistakes further down in the method chain.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

It appears that the notification method was causing the error because it was also calling `Context.SaveChanges`

You only need to call `Context.SaveChanges` once

I would remove the `Context.SaveChanges` in the notification method, only calling it once at the end of the transaction scope.

Comment: "You shouldn't access a Context in a foreach loop like that."   **why**?

Comment: Well a similar problem arises when you try to enumerate over an IEnumerable in a foreach loop. It attempts to enumerate every time it iterates over the loop.

Comment: The nice thing about our profession is that code is predictable. "Weird things" do not just happen, there is always a reason why a component or piece of code behaves the way it does. I have yet to encounter a problem with a piece of code that could not be explained in a logical manner. Adding "weird things happen when..." to an answer simply invalidates everything else that comes after it (IMO).

Comment: Okay i'll copy and paste my comment in the post to appease people in our profession such as yourself. EDIT: Nevermind.