# .net standard class library - not support Distributed Transaction error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, class-library, .net-standard

I developed a logging service in .net standard class library project. It is perfectly working without **System.Transaction** *(TransactionScope class)*. 

When I add transaction to a process, logger insert method throws an exception. 
[**This platform does not support distributed transactions.**]

When I add code to core console app with System.Transaction it works.

Is **.net standard** not supporting System.Transaction(TransactionScope)?

***NOTE:*** 
For now : .net core and nugets are lastest.

- Distribution Transaction Coordinator service is working,
- EF Core version: 2.1.0 preview2-final,
- Class library versions .NET Standard 2.0
- AspNetCore 2.0.5

***Edit:*** 

I realized that exception throws when I try to open second connection in same database with in the same TransactionScope block. 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203394/3302306)

Comment: Which Netstandard are you targeting? `netstandard2.0` and `netcoreapp20` shouldn't support it, but `netstandard2.1`/`netcoeapp2.0` And keep in mind "Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) " is windows only and not available on linux and mac which is required for distributed transactions

Comment: in property page, dropdown of target framework contains only _.NET Standard 1.0_ to _2.0_ and my class library target framework is `.NET Standard 2.0`

Comment: The latest version of .NET Standard is 2.0. 

Which platform are you running this code on? Do you have a small code sample to share?

Comment: I would encourage you to upvote and/or comment on the official issue for this missing feature: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/13532

Answer (score 5):

The error message you are mentioning points to this is running on .NET Core and that you are trying to use/create a Distributed Transaction.

Browsing the code for DistributedTransaction in the [CoreFx repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b09fab5799bb1ca4bea4b4bb086d2c9870dd5191/src/System.Transactions.Local/src/System/Transactions/DistributedTransaction.cs) it looks like Distributed Transactions are not supported on .NET Core.

Comment: In .net core console app, log insertion works successfully with System.Transaction (TransactionScope class ). If .NET Core is not support , I guess it shouldn't work

Comment: Where are you seeing the issue if this works on ..NET Core?