# How can i use distributed transaction in .Net Core 2.1?

Tags: transactions, .net-core

We are migrating our project .net framework to .net core Web API. we have used TransactionScope for maintaining rollback and commit operation in .net framework.It also allowed distributed transaction from single TransactionScope. Means it allows to perform DML statement for multiple DB from single transaction.

Now in .net core, distributed transaction is not supported.Its throw the error :

> "This platform does not support distributed transactions"

Can someone provide me an example of its implementation into .Net Core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.net standard class library - not support Distributed Transaction error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177520/net-standard-class-library-not-support-distributed-transaction-error)